# Adding ofl to dynamic links firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, desktop, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to add ofl so when the link is opened on a desktop it will go to the web version of the app

Here's my code where should I add it?

```
final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      // The Dynamic Link URI domain. You can view created URIs on your Firebase console
      uriPrefix: uriPrefix,

      // The deep Link passed to your application which you can use to affect change
      link: Uri.parse(parsableLink),
      // Android application details needed for opening correct app on device/Play Store
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
          packageName: androidPackageName, fallbackUrl: Uri.parse(webLink)),

      // iOS application details needed for opening correct app on device/App Store
      iosParameters: IOSParameters(
          bundleId: iosPackageName, fallbackUrl: Uri.parse(webLink)),

      //longDynamicLink: Uri.parse('$parsableLink&ofl=$webLink')
    );

    final ShortDynamicLink shortDynamicLink =
        await dynamicLinks.buildShortLink(parameters);
    print(shortDynamicLink);

    return shortDynamicLink.shortUrl.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured that out I had to add the longDynamicLink like this :

```
"$uriPrefix/?link=$parsableLink&apn=$androidPackageName&afl=$webLink&ibi=$iosPackageName&isi=$iosId&ifl=$webLink&ofl=$webLink"
```